# Cakephp v2.4.1, validation of group of separate radio buttons - need to enforce that one is checked

Tags: php, cakephp

I have four separate radio buttons as below and I need to do the validation in the Model, I have used some jquery to allow only one button to be used, and this works but can't figure out how to do the validation within the model if no button is checked, any help would really save my neck:

```
$options = array('A1' => 'A1' );
$attributes = array(
 'legend'=>False ,
 'label'=>true,
 'class'=>'g' , 
 //'before'=>'',
 //'after'=>'',
 'separator'=>'' );
echo $this->Form->radio('a1', $options, $attributes); 



$options = array('A2' => 'A2' );
$attributes = array(
 'legend'=>False,
 'label'=>true, 
  'class'=>'g' , 
 //'before'=>'',
 //'after'=>'',
 'separator'=>'' );
echo $this->Form->radio('a2', $options, $attributes); 



$options = array('B1' => 'B1' );
$attributes = array(
 'legend'=>False,
 'label'=>true, 
  'class'=>'g' , 
 //'before'=>'',
 //'after'=>'',
 'separator'=>'' );
echo $this->Form->radio('b1', $options, $attributes); 


$options = array('B2' => 'B2' );
$attributes = array(
 'legend'=>False,
 'label'=>true, 
  'class'=>'g' , 
 //'before'=>'',
 //'after'=>'',
 'separator'=>'' );
echo $this->Form->radio('b2', $options, $attributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you'd want to go that way as the whole point of radio buttons is to have only one option clicked at a time. No need for JS or anything. I would pass just one `Form::radio` with the 4 options and handle the input in my controller if it had to be different fields.

But if you want to do it like you have it planned then you need a [custom validation rule](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules). Make a new rule that will check all said fields from `$this->data` and return true only if just one of them is set.

Comment: I wanted to use go that way but I need to save each diferent option to different coloum in the DB, I thought that the mapping to the DB was taken from the name of the Radio button set, If you can tell me how to handle the input from the controler that would be really appreciated, I am new to cakephp and  of a designer rather that a developer but want to learn!

Comment: Assuming you use in your form `$this->Form->input('radioOption', $options);` where `$options = array('a1' => 'a1', 'b1' => 'b1');`, you will be getting the selected value at `$this->data['Model']['radioOption']`. You can then do a `switch` or `if`...`elseif` to set the appropriate database field with i.e. `$this->Model->set('a1', true);`. You obviously have to replace `Model` with your model name. And of course there are more than one way to do that.